# Control single-light LED strip with Raspberry pi and MOSFET

Tags: raspberry-pi, led-strip

I'm trying to make my LED strip fade-in and fade-out by using Raspberry-pi 4, unfortunately for me, I am not an electronic expert. Every tutorial I saw so far was for RGB LED strips and I have a single-color (3000 K) LED strip with just 2 pins (+ & -).
I have:

1. LRS-50-24 [datasheet](https://www.meanwell.com/Upload/PDF/LRS-50/LRS-50-SPEC.PDF)
2. 30N06L [datasheet](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/General/FQP30N06L.pdf)
3. 4m LED strip single color (3000K) 24V
4. Raspberry Pi 4
   [image]

My question is how to connect the MOSFET and the LRS-50-24 to the PI in order to control the fade-in/out by GPIO python code?

Appreciate any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I take it that you'd be using the GPIOs PWM function to generate pulses to toggle the LEDs quickly on and off to control the light level.

You can connect the gate (G) of the FET to a GPIO. The source (S) to the negative output of the power supply and the led strip between the positive and the drain (D).

Of course you'll have to connect the negative terminal of the power supply also to the GND of the Raspberry Pi.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJz3z9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I've added an optional resistor (R1) in the schmatic that will discharge the gate if the GPIO is in high-impedance state or disconnected. This prevents the FET from staying "switched on".

Another optional resistor (R2) limits the momentary current when switching the FET on or off. (See comments).

Also worth mentioning is that the FET you've chosen (FQP30N06L) has low enough gate threshold voltage (VGS(th)) that it probably will work ok with the Pi for this application. Certain other FETs with higher VGS(th) might not work at all. For example this [30N06L](https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf-file/817129/UTC/30N06L/1) from Unisonic possibly won't.

Comment: Can you add a schematic? The OP is very unsure and new to the subject. The schematic tool here is a breeze to use or you can add an existing diagram if relevant, just not a giant photo of a sketch. Thanks, will happily upvote if fixed.

Comment: It will be great if you could add schematic @TrayMan

Comment: Seeing as there will be hundreds of switching operations per second and the maximum output current for an RPi 4 GPIO pin is 16 mA, would a gate resistor of a few tens of ohms be a good idea? Or maybe even a BJT to drive the MOSFET?

Comment: @AndrewMorton Why would you add a resistor? To reduce EMI? I suppose that might be sensible, if the leads are long. I could add it to the schematic. Sure, a BJT to drive the FET would work (to handle higher VGS(th)), but is a bit more complicated and might not be necessary. I'd rather recommend using another device entirely.

Comment: Just a side note about driving MOSFET gates from a non-engineer hobbyist:  Adding a gate driver is both relatively cheap and easier for a novice than building your own gate drive, and performs ridiculously better than driving a MOSFET from a weak pin.  That said it's rare you'd strictly need more than ~400hz for an LED so you can get away with relatively slow switching.

Comment: @TrayMan I followed your instructions but the LED ON no matter what I do.

Comment: @Omri Sounds a bit like the GPIO isn't ever driver low. Can you toggle the GPIO between 0 and 1 in software? If so, can you measure 0 and 3.3V with respect to the ground at the GPIO pin using a volt meter?

Comment: @TrayMan yes, the GPIO pin outputs 0.39-1.66v. Im using pigpio command named set_PWM_dutycycle(pin, brightness) and the brightness possible values are 0-255. when 0 the pin is 0.39V and when 255 the pin is 1.66V. Also, I have checked the Gate and Source pins and its showing 0.93V when brightness set to 255. and ideas?

Comment: @Omri Try without the PWM feature. Just try toggling the LED on and off first. If that works, you have some issue with the PWM. You'd really need an oscilloscope to measure how the PWM works properly. Maybe try setting the PWM frequency to a lower value?

Comment: @TrayMan good news. I changed the MOSFET to IRLB8721 and its working. BUT the power of the LED lights is very weak... Any suggestions on how to make it stronger?

Comment: @Omri That's hard to say. If the gate voltage is too low, the FET doesn't conduct very well. Can you drive the FET gate directly with, say, 4.5V or 5V instead of the Raspberry Pi to test to see if the LEDs light up properly like that? If the problem is too low voltage from the GPIO, you'll need a driver circuit for the gate. Also, you should've been able to at least turn the LEDs off with the other FET. If they turned on with the other FET, it should've been fine with that.

Comment: @TrayMan my guess is that the FET does not fit this circuit. With IRLB8721  I managed to check 3.3V when brightness is high(255) and 0V when low(0). Any suggestions on what MOSFET will be good for this project?

Comment: @Omri The gate doesn't really affect the voltage in any way, so you should be able to measure 0 and 3.3V even with the FQP30N06L, unless it's broken. FDN337N would be good, but it's in an SMD package. I couldn't find any good ones with integrated driver circuits, but if you need a driver, the circuit looks like this: https://arduinodiy.files.wordpress.com/2012/05/fet2.gif except you can use 5V from the Pi instead of 12V. Perhaps someone will write another answer with that circuit.